# Send presence while not chatting with anyone

Tags: android, quickblox

What is the best way to send presence to the server. Currently I am using multiple times     QBAuth.createSession(this); but I think there should be abetter way to send presence then to auth/login every time?

P.S. I don't want to connect with any user to send my presence status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
con.sendPacket(presence);
```

http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/gettingstarted.html